# LWUIT gui builder for eclipse

Tags: java-me, lwuit

is there any GUI builder plugin available for LWUIT in eclipse like it is in netbeans???

or you have to hand code just about everything?

Answer (score 0):

The resource editor isn't bound to the IDE but it isn't well integrated with Eclipse due to the unique structure of Eclipse. In theory you could use it with Eclipse although it would be a hassle.

[Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/) is essentially a LWUIT fork that goes way beyond the abilities of LWUIT and has an Eclipse version that includes the designer tool.